# Handing complex data transformations with pivot_table in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I am working a `pandas DataFrame` of a shape of `7837 rows and 19 columns`. I am interested in getting the number of times a `product_id` appears per month which is the `date` column, and the associated `amount`. Because a `product_id` can have various amounts. So I am looking for a way to say for example `product_id` 1921 with `amount` 59 appeared ....

Here is the small version of the `pandas dataframe`

```
print(df)

     CompanyName        Produktname     product_id    amount       Date
0     companyA            productA        1921         59.0       Jan-2020
1     companyB            productB        114          NaN        May-2020
2     companyC            productC        469          NaN        Feb-2020
3     companyD            productD        569          18.0       Jun-2020
4     companyE            productE        569          18.0      March-2020
```

I think pivot_table might be helpful. I wanted to first see how many times each product_id appeared with the date as the column

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index="product_id", values= "product_id" ,columns="Date", aggfunc="count")
```

but I get an error:

```
ValueError: Grouper for 'product_id' not 1-dimensional
```

Is there a way around this or a more efficient way to handle this?

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index="product_id", values= "amount" ,columns="Date", aggfunc="count")` ?

Comment: it seems you need change `values= "product_id"` to `values= "amount"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index="product_id", values= "amount" ,columns="Date", aggfunc="count")
print (df)
Date        Feb-2020  Jan-2020  Jun-2020  March-2020  May-2020
product_id                                                    
114              NaN       NaN       NaN         NaN       0.0
469              0.0       NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN
569              NaN       NaN       1.0         1.0       NaN
1921             NaN       1.0       NaN         NaN       NaN
```

For correct order is possible use:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b-%Y')
df = df.pivot_table(index="product_id", 
                    values= "amount" ,
                    columns="Date", 
                    aggfunc="count", 
                    fill_value=0).rename(columns = lambda x: x.strftime('%b-%Y'))
print (df)
Date        Jan-2020  Feb-2020  Mar-2020  May-2020  Jun-2020
product_id                                                  
114                0         0         0         0         0
469                0         0         0         0         0
569                0         0         1         0         1
1921               1         0         0         0         0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! One question, a `product_id` has various `amount`. How do I know the amounts for each `product_id`. What is it doing under the hood? Did it aggregate the count of the `amount` from a `product_id`. More explanation, a `product_id`  114 can have different amounts like 50, 100, 200. Lets they appear 2,3,4 times respectively. Is it doing an aggregation of all the count from an `amount` in a `product_id`

Comment: @Pythonista - I am a bit confued, you need `, aggfunc="sum"` instead `, aggfunc="count"` ?

Comment: Is it possible to have `product_id` as the `index` and use the `product_id` as the `values`?

Comment: @Pythonista - possible solution with new column `df = df.assign(new = df['product_id']).pivot_table(index="product_id", values= "amount" ,columns="new", aggfunc="count")`